# unable to generate mapping method from Enum To Boolean by MapStruct

Tags: java, maven, mapping, mapstruct

I can use succesfully  from enum to enum by using mapstruct which converts one object type to another object type.

Unfortunately, I am not able to convert Enum to Boolaen. I get following error.

"Can't map property "ChoiceType isPriceHigh" to "java.lang.Boolean isPriceHigh". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "java.lang.Boolean map(ChoiceType value)".

Here is the method that I use at mapstruct. Any help will be appreciated.

Cheers
Alper

```
@ValueMappings({
        @ValueMapping(target = "true", source = "YES"),
        @ValueMapping(target = "false", source = "NO")
})
Boolean map(ChoiceType value);
```

Comment: what type does `source` expect?

Comment: source expects EnumType(ChoiceType), and target should be boolean such like True and False

Comment: do they need to be declared as strings? Maybe the following might be the correct way: `@ValueMapping(target = true, source = ChoiceType.YES),
        @ValueMapping(target = false, source = ChoiceType.NO)`

Comment: Lino it gives me compile time error. for target= true it says "Incompatible types . Found boolean required String. For source = ChoiceType.Yes it says  found ChoiceType required String. Here is the code That I wrote after your offer.     @ValueMappings({
            @ValueMapping(target = true, source = ChoiceType.YES),
            @ValueMapping(target = false, source = ChoiceType.NO)
    })
    Boolean map(ChoiceType value);

Comment: well both `target` and `source` require strings so my suggestion can't be used

Comment: any more suggestions ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`@ValueMappings` can be used to map between `enum`(s) and not object and `enum`. `Boolean` in Java is not an `enum` and that is the reason why you are getting the error.

In order to do such mapping you will have to define your own method for it.

```java
public interface MyMapper {

    default Boolean map(ChoiceType value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }

        switch(value) {
            case YES:
                return true;
            case NO:
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and it has to be implemented from my main Mapper interface ?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can do it in it's own class, interface, util class. You just need to make sure that you add that class, interface, util class in `Mapper@uses` so MapStruct can pick it up and use it